# Handling POST request (String) generated by Volley at web server

Tags: android, rest, http-post

I have made an android app which collects certain data from android  device and then posts them as string to restful web server to receive corresponding response from server. I'm using volley methods to `POST` request. My code for sending data is as under:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
String url ="server url";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
               showOutput("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
           }
       },new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               showOutput("That didn't work!");
           }
       }){
           @Override
           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
               params.put("query Type", "query Num");
               params.put("para1", "test data 1");
               params.put("para2", "test data 2");
               return params;
           }
       };

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**Edited:**

In order to respond to this request from android device, I have created a web service using tomcat web container and jersey library.... Using curl I have checked that server is returning string for both `GET` and `POST` request. However, when i send POST/GET query from android device, the response lands up in ErrorListener. The java class which handles get/post request at server, along with various options that I've tried is as under:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
  return "Hello GET String";
  } 
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String post(@QueryParam("param1")String param1, @QueryParam("param2")String param2){
    String msg = param1+param2;
    return msg;
  }
/*
  public Response post(@QueryParam("param1")String param1, @QueryParam("param2")String param2){
    String msg = param1+param2;
    return Response.ok(msg).build();
  }
  public Response post(@QueryParam("param1")String param1, @QueryParam("param2")String param2){
    String msg = param1+param2;
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
  public Response post(@Context UriInfo ui){
  MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams =ui.getQueryParameters();
    String msg = param1+param2;
    Response r = null;
  return r;
  }
*/
}
```

I am unable to get help to: receive the strings sent by the android device in POST request, process them and send back string as response to post query.

Any help would be appretiated...

Comment: may i please know why has the question been downgraded....i'll ammend it...

Comment: Could you tell me what message returns if you execute the command `curl -X POST http://yourhost.com/yourpostwebservice`? BTW aren't you missing an annotation in the `Hello` class?

Comment: Because there you are sending a GET request, and with curl you send a POST one...

Comment: But, with that error that you are getting, your tomcat shouldn't be running! What are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: @astinx on typing the above command on server machine there is no response...i just get the next $ sign

Comment: linux, earlier response was because of wrong cmd

Comment: It should return "hello". The url routing of that controller seems to have something odd. I would recommend you get that server working first. It's been ages since the last time that I used jersey but AFAIK I think that some annotation is missing in that controller. And with what other tech are you using Jersey, Spring?

Comment: thanks i'll come back again

Comment: `The java class which handles get request successfully is as under:

public class Hello`. In no way. That class does not hanle requests. It can only produce a string.

Comment: @greenapps Not understood!

Comment: I have edited the class Hello. Tested with curl, getting response for both GET and POST. Please help solve the initially posted question: How to receive the strings sent by the android device in POST request, process them and send back string as response to post query.

Comment: I have updated the options that I have tried to receive params from request and send a Response, but non have succeeded....please suggest something..

Comment: apologies for being such a dumb .... the above solution worked on restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for being such a dumb .... the above solution worked on restart !!

android device is receiving the post response string of the POST query !!!